# Industrial connectors with fail-safe disconnect under cable tension (like MagSafe)

Tags: connector, cables

Background/problem:

We install electronic monitoring systems on semi-mobile industrial equipment. The environment is harsh and sometimes our cables are treated in a very rough manner. This can result in cable breaks (usually at the connector terminating the cable into our equipment). This is a problem because at a minimum we then need to replace/repair the cable; at worse a short can damage our electronics.

We currently use Deutsch connectors which are extremely sturdy and waterproof.

The question:

Does anyone know of industrial cable connectors that operate with the same purpose as Apple's MagSafe safe disconnect? Ideally if someone yanks one of our cables I want the cable to disconnect rather than breaking.

Comment: If your connectors are in an industrial environment, a mag-safe style jack using magnets for the hold-together force is a disaster waiting to happen. It'll suck in metal chips or dust, and fry something.

Answer (score 4):

[LEMO](http://www.lemo.com/) makes a nice line of "push-pull" latching connectors. I can't find it now, but I seem to recall seeing that they had a way of attaching a lanyard or cable to the release mechanism, so that if you pulled on it, the connector would separate. You could anchor the release cable to the electrical cable so that the former is shorter than the latter, such that if you
put enough tension on the far end of the cable, the connector will release before all of the slack is gone in the loop of electrical cable.

Of course, this will probably only work if the direction of the pull is more or less in-line with the axis of the connector, but you might be able to arrange some sort of ring-shaped guide that the cable must pass through that helps insure that this is the case.

I hope my description is clear; if not, I'll try to sketch what I have in mind.

Comment: You might want to sit down before reading the price list though...

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are looking for are called breakaway connectors.  Amphenol, ITT cannon & molex all have variations.  A company called Souriau have a [push/pull breakaway](http://www.souriau-industrial.com/en/content/download/8089/37609/version/1/file/PushPull-Pamphlet.pdf) (opens a *.pdf) connector system.  All very expensive.

Answer (score 1):

Another brand is from Rosenberger [1][2]. I only used the medical ones though.

[1] http://www.rosenberger.de/en/products/medical/magnetic.php

[2] http://www.rosenberger.de/en/products/automotive/magcode.php